# Google App Script unverified app for own use and development

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got the problem of having an unverified app. I don't think I should need to verify my app as I am the only user and developer of it, and that won't change. Why does it want me to verify the app and how do I fix this problem?

Comment: [Here is Google's take on that](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) - I am guessing a lot of it has to do with the [Google Docs hack](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2017/05/03/why-this-google-docs-phishing-attack-is-particularly-sneaky/?utm_term=.1cd91dac2f38) some months back.

Comment: Is there any easy way of getting past that for own use only?

Comment: If its just for your use, why not just [go through](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) the **Figure 2** `Unverified app authorization flow` once and it wont take you back to that screen unless you add code that requires additional authorization. As far as I know, each account that wants to run the code has to authorize it - it's not smart enough to know that it is your original code and that it is you executing it without authorization. But I think it is mostly to make people not just blindly click through like in that Google Docs phishing attack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having an unverified app is not a "problem" if it is for your own use. It only means a couple of extra clicks (Advanced, etc) when access to a new service is added to the app (for example, you included access to MailApp in addition to SpreadsheetApp).  The [unverified app flow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) may look scary but since you know what you are doing, it should not stop you for more than a second.

You cannot disable this security measure. It is meant to protect uninformed users from themselves. Such measures tend to be annoying to users who know exactly what they are doing. But Google can't tell the difference between someone who develops own apps and someone who pastes in dangerously buggy or malicious code they found on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I missed the part on the advanced screen on the unauthorized auth flow popup where you can choose to go to the app anyway